# Wacom art pen rotation support?

Tags: wacom

I've been experimenting with different programs in ubuntu with my Cintiq. It works pretty well, but I cannot seem to get rotation recognized with the art pen and internet searching is not yielding any results. Is pen rotation supported in linux?

Comment: As I understand it, the short answer is yes. [This resource on the Wacom tablet](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wacom_Tablet) may help.

Comment: This description of [configuring a Wacom Cintiq model](http://ragnarb.com/configuring-wacom-cintiq-13hd-with-ubuntu-14-04/) may also be helpful, although the author is using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Which Cintiq is is?  (lsusb | grep Wacom)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does support it but may depend on the program.

Thanks for those links in the comments, they actually didn't pop in my google searches.

I'm using a cintiq 21UX. I got it working, but I am not entirely sure what the problem was. I experimented with various distros seeing if I could get my various interests(games, art) working with my hardware, specifically and AMD video card and my cintiq. After a lot of effort and searching I ended up going with linux mint 18.1 and upgraded the kernel to the last 4.8 version. After doing that I was able to successfully install the latest proprietary AMD drivers. Then I downloaded a Krita app image and test out some brushes with my cintiq. It worked.

I think something that could have been different is I previously installed krita via snap and perhaps those versions were different. I'm guessing different software and maybe even versions of software handle the support differently. The app image seems to work just fine, so I'm pretty happily going along in linux now.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: and Mint 18.1 offers the 4.10 kernel as an easy-install option too

Comment: unfortunately I was not able to get the AMD drivers working on the 4.10 kernel. It crashed every time.